# Highcharts gauge chart size

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I've been trying to make the gauge thinner. I succeeded a little by making the innerRadius 90%, but I'm unable to change the size of the green section. It's always bigger. I tried playing around with 'outerRadius' too but lo luck so far.

```
var gaugeOptions = {

  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge'
  },

  title: null,

  pane: {
    center: ['30%', '85%'],
    size: '150%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#EEE',
      innerRadius: '110%',
      outerRadius: '85%',
      shape: 'arc'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },

  // the value axis
  yAxis: {
    stops: [
      [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
      [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
      [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
    ],
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorTickInterval: null,
    tickAmount: 2,
    title: {
      y: -70
    },
    labels: {
      y: 16
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        y: 5,
        borderWidth: 0,
        useHTML: true
      }
    }
  }
};

// The speed gauge
var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('container-speed', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Speed',
    data: [20],
    dataLabels: {
      format: '<div style="text-align:center">' +
        '<span style="font-size:25px">{y}</span><br/>' +
        '<span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">km/h</span>' +
        '</div>'
    }
  }]

}));
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv13f9g8/). I'm basically trying to make the green match the grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set `radius` and `innerRadius` properties on a series level:

```
    series: [{
        radius: 90,
        innerRadius: 105,
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fwumc7db/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.innerRadius

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.radius

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the green section can be set by add properties `radius` and `innerRadius` in `series.data`.
In your case, it should be:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Speed',
  data: [{
    y: 20,
    radius: 90,
    innerRadius: 105
  }],
  dataLabels: {...}
}]
```

more info [here](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41500)